# Changing the message (or exception) in WPF ValidatesOnException binding

Tags: wpf, validation

I have a WPF application using MVVM.
I am using binding to a POCO object.

The Textbox is bound to a property in the object like:

```
           <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="CertainProperty" Mode="TwoWay" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
```

Now this property is a a int property and when the user tried to enter a non-numeric value, they get the "input string was not in a correct format".
What I need to do is customize this message to a more user friendly one.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that exception and its message originate deep within the framework code and can't simply be swapped out. But one thing you can do is circumvent the exception completely by writing your own `ValidationRule`. For example:

```
public class Int32ValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;

        int number;
        return int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out number)
            ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
            : new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid integer");
    }
}
```

Of course, the nuclear option is to turn `CertainProperty` into a `string` and let your viewmodel or model validate it via `IDataErrorInfo`, but that would be a major change from your existing code.